# XML to dataset Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm stuck.  I don't use XML much. But, I need to pull some info from a web site, put it in a dataset, do some validations, then add it to a database.  Thought this would be pretty straight forward with the dataset.ReadXML function... but it's not... I get one row and one item as a result of my code - server time.  I put the ds in a datagridview just to check it, and it shows only the server time. I don't get it...  Any help would be appreciated!  Here's my code and the xml it should return (checked it with an xmlreader function)

```vb
Dim strISBN As String
strISBN = "9780399155161"

Dim strISBNDB As String = "http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=???&results=subjects&index1=isbn&value1=" & strISBN

Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml(strISBNDB)

DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager
```

XML:

```xml
<ISBNdb server_time="2014-09-21T07:06:24Z">
<BookList total_results="1" page_size="10" page_number="1" shown_results="1">
<BookData book_id="scarpetta" isbn="0399155163" isbn13="9780399155161">
<Title>Scarpetta</Title>
<TitleLong></TitleLong>
<AuthorsText>Patricia Cornwell</AuthorsText>
<PublisherText publisher_id="g_p_putnams_sons">New York : G. P. Putnam's Sons, c2008./PublisherText>
<Subjects>
<Subject subject_id="literature_fiction_contemporary">Literature &amp; Fiction -- Contemporary</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="mystery_thrillers_thrillers">Mystery &amp; Thrillers -- Thrillers</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="scarpetta_kay_fictitious_character_fiction">Scarpetta, Kay (Fictitious character) -- Fiction</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="medical_examiners_law_fiction">Medical examiners (Law) -- Fiction</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="mystery_fiction">Mystery fiction</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="forensic_pathologists_fiction">Forensic pathologists -- Fiction</Subject>
<Subject subject_id="women_physicians_fiction">Women physicians -- Fiction</Subject>
</Subjects>
</BookData>
</BookList>
</ISBNdb>
```

Comment: Is that exactly the xml being returned? PublisherText is not closed properly.

Comment: yup.  i hadn't noticed that. probably why i'm getting some errors. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ds.ReadXml is interpreting most of the elements as their own DataTable. When I run your code with that XML (PublisherText element closed properly) I get 6 datatables. You must only be looking at the first since that is what contains the server_time. 
Observe the debug visualizer of the DataSet:
[image]

Comment: well...darn it...never occurred to me it would create multiple datatables. any way to force the xml into one?

Comment: That xml heirarchy wouldn't fit into one table. If It weren't for the many to one <Subjects> you could probably craft an xml schema that would load it into one table.

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought too. guess a loop and add is gonna be all i can do...

Answer (score 1):

This string *strISBNDB* doesn't contain valid *XML*. In fact, it contains the following:

> `http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=???&results=subjects&index1=isbn&value1=9780399155161`

You need to obtain the *XML*. Here's an example using the `WebClient` class.

```vb
Dim ds As New DataSet

Using client As New WebClient()
    ds.ReadXml(client.OpenRead(strISBNDB)))
End Using

ds.ReadXml(strISBNDB)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, and I get an error "root element is missing".